# Autocorrelation in Tail Events

Tags: finance, time-series

I have a single time series of financial data (stock index returns) and would like to study the autocorrelation among (log-)returns that are classified as "extreme", for example via exceedance of a certain threshold. The threshold could be defined by some quantile (5% for example). From filtering the data I can see that this kind of returns commonly occur in clusters.

My first idea was to use the build in (1)CorrelationFunction[] or (2)PartialCorrelationFunction[]. To maintain the temporal structure of my data set I replaced returns that did not pass the threshold level with Missing[] and applied Function (1) and (2). However, both functions do not produce any reasonable output.

Any comment on the approach itself or alternatives is much appreciated.

Comment: So far no comments, mainly because your question is too broad and unspecific. Statements such as *"do not produce any reasonable output."* do not explain a concrete problem that we can help you to solve. Please [edit] your question, share your code and example data, and give an example of expected output contrasted with real output.